# Sparse Categorical CrossEntropy shape problem with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, classification

I have a multiclass problem where an image can be one of three classes (Masked, UnMasked, Hybrid).

I am using **image_dataset_from_directory** from keras preprocessing module which makes things easier.

### Load dataset

```py
def load_from_directory(shuffle=False):
  train_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAINING_PATH,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset='training',
    label_mode='int',
    shuffle=shuffle
  )

  val_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TRAINING_PATH,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    subset='validation',
    label_mode='int',
    shuffle=False
  )

  test_ds = tfk.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=TESTING_PATH,
    labels=None,
    image_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=SEED,
    label_mode='int',
    shuffle=False
  )

  return train_ds, val_ds, test_ds
```

On the keras documentation it states for the label_model the following: **'int': means that the labels are encoded as integers (e.g. for sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss) ...** ([here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) is the link). Since my folder has the following structure:

- MaskDataset

  - training

    - 0/

      - img1, img2, …, imgN
    - 1/

      - img1, img2, …, imgN
    - 2/

      - img1, img2, …, imgN
  - testing

    - img1, img2, …, imgN

And for the model by final layers are the following:

```py
  x = tfkl.SeparableConv2D(1024, 3, padding='same')(x)
  x = tfkl.BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = tfkl.Activation('relu')(x)  

  # GlobalAveragePooling + Dropout
  x = tfkl.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = tfkl.Dropout(0.5)(x) 
  
  # Softmax
  outputs = tfkl.Dense(units=len(CLASS_NAMES), activation='softmax')(x)

  model = tfk.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

which I get the following complain:
"ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible"

If I change the label_mode to 'categorical', when loading the dataset and change the loss function from SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy to CategoricalCrossEntropy and the accuracy from SparseCategoricalAccuracy to CategoricalAccuracy it works, but I really wanted to understand why I am not able to use the SparseCrossEntropy loss function and how to fix it.

### Edit: Add model compile and fit

```py
def compile_model(model, plot=False):
  model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(name='loss'),
    metrics=[
      tfk.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'), 
      tfk.metrics.Precision(name='precision'), 
      tfk.metrics.Recall(name='recall'), 
    ]
  )

  model.summary()
  if plot: tfk.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

def train_model(model, debug_mode=False):
  callbacks = [tfk.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, monitor='val_loss', restore_best_weights=True)]
  if debug_mode:
    callbacks.append(tfk.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss'))
    callbacks.append(tfk.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./tensorboard'))

  history = model.fit(
    x=train_ds, 
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=100, 
    callbacks=callbacks,
    # steps_per_epoch=len(train_ds),
    # validation_steps=len(val_ds),
  )

  return history
```

Comment: Just added more info @AloneTogether. I can share the entire notebook if you prefer

Comment: Here it is: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v64qerR4G-FfObNbpX5bn4e1avL80AeX?usp=sharing

If you find any thing wrong you can leave a comment directly there of here. I also added the link to the dataset if you want to run it locally (in the Data Loading section)

Comment: @vscv suggested: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132691/use-different-metrics-in-tf-keras-metrics-for-mutli-classification-model

You have to use a one-hot class if you want to use any metric naming without the 'Sparse'.

Answer (score 0):

tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy() --> is for SparseCategorical (int) class. tf.keras.metrics.Recall() --> is for categorical (one-hot) class.

You have to use a one-hot class if you want to use any metric naming without the 'Sparse'.

update:

```
num_class=4
def get_img_and_onehot_class(img_path, class):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    """ Other preprocessing of image."""
    return img, tf.one_hot(class, num_class)
```

when you got the one-hot class:

```
loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy
METRICS=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),]

model.compile(
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
        loss=loss,
        metrics= METRICS)
```

Ref:[#72217176](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132691/use-different-metrics-in-tf-keras-metrics-for-mutli-classification-model/72217176#72217176)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31758324)