# Use different metrics in tf.keras.metrics for mutli-classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

I am using the TensorFlow federated framework for
a multiclassification problem. I am following the [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) and most of them use the metric (`tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy`) to measure the models' accuracy.
I wanted to explore the other measures like (AUC, recall, F1, and precision) but I am getting the errors.
The code and the error message are provided below.

```
def create_keras_model():
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, kernel_initializer=initializer),
      tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
  ])
def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=train_data[0].element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
               tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]
      )
```

The error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None,) are incompatible
```

Is it because of the muti classification problem, that we cannot use these measures with it? and if so, is there any other metric I may use to measure my multi-classification model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy() --> is for SparseCategorical  (int) class.
tf.keras.metrics.Recall() --> is for categorical  (one-hot) class.

You have to use a one-hot class if you want to use any metric naming without the 'Sparse'.

update:

```
num_class=4
def get_img_and_onehot_class(img_path, class):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    """ Other preprocessing of image."""
    return img, tf.one_hot(class, num_class)
```

when you got the one-hot class:

```
loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy
METRICS=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),]

model.compile(
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
        loss=loss,
        metrics= METRICS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's really helpful. Well, I want to ask further, I changed the data to one-hot classes. I am having 4 labels, what will be the number of the last layer in the neural network (the output layer)? **and** for the target and features columns, can I select all 4 columns as targets?

Comment: @Alwani You don't need to change the output number of the Dense layer. Just keep it as it is.

Comment: Thanks, but I just got confused and the results are not that good. The target columns became now 4 columns, would I use them all as the target column in the splitting code from the target and featurs?

Comment: Not sure what problem you are referring to. I suggest that you can start with a simple tf.keras model, make sure that the training is correct, and then put it in tensorflow-federated.